# jQuery Val() not working when trying to pre select dynamic values

Tags: jquery, node.js, ejs

In hard-coded and default value fields, `$("#id").val(id)` is working fine, but in this case scenario, I couldn't make a preselection.

Edit: `_id` is an ObjId from mongoDb

ejs

```
                         <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Hotel</label>
                                <select
                                    id="hotelId"
                                    name="hotelId"
                                    class="select2 form-control"
                                    data-placeholder="Select Hotel"
                                    style="width: 100%"
                                >
                                    <% stays.forEach(stay => { %>
                                    <option value="<%=stay._id%>"><%= stay.name %></option>
                                    <% }) %>
                                </select>
                              </div>
```

---

Script

```
let hotelId = '<%- JSON.stringify(room.hotelId._id) %>';
$('#hotelId').val(hotelId);
```

Comment: [How to ask a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Essentially, you have a bug, but your question does not show enough information about the values in play to give an answer.

Comment: just solved the problem, looks like, in order to use it as a value, we need to parse it first

Comment: is *_id* a numeric or string, or is it a complex object?  The way it looks, is that you are trying to stringify an integer or somethng and then referencing it. The way i read it is that hotel id is going to be a json string.   You should give more definition of what _id would be

Comment: @Fallenreaper you are right, the _id is an objId form Mongo Db. I will Update the question for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by parsing it, Maybe because it is an objId

```
 $('#hotelId').val(JSON.parse(hotelId));
```

Comment: A high proportion of bugs are caused by coder assumptions about the conditions in affect at the time of the problem. I do not know for sure but I reckon this might also be inversely related to age.  When you get an issue like this the optimum approach is to confirm your assumptions before taking any other action - in this case that the 'actual' hotelId value matched one of the options in the select. Would have taken single use of F12 in the browser and inspecting the page elements in question.

Comment: Yup, already used debugger, it showed the ID without parsing it.  If you know why the behavior is like that let me know.